# Ordenar un ArrayList de arrays de enteros

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo el siguiente problema.
Estoy intentando ordenar un ArrayList por sus elementos. Dichos elementos son arrays de enteros.

```
ArrayList <int[]> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
```

El resultado que obtengo actualmente cuando imprimo por pantalla el ArrayList es:

```
[2, 0, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[1, 2, 0, 3]
```

Pero yo quiero ordenar dicho ArrayList primero y obtener como resultado:

```
[1, 2, 0, 3]
[1, 3, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 3, 1]
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.
Un saludo!

Comment: Cuál es el criterio de ordenamiento? parece orden inverso nada más

Comment: El criterio sería que primero ordena los arrays por el primer elemento, si ambos son iguales por el segundo, y así sucesivamente. No solo son los 2 primeros sino todos los elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza [`Collection.sort`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp) para ordenar el ArrayList para ello debes incluir `import java.util.Collections;`

Enseguida debes implementar un `Comparator` que como indicas en tu ejemplo el orden afecta el primer y segundo término (posición 0 y 1) a los cuales debes realizar la comparación.

```
ArrayList<int[]> resultados = new ArrayList<int[]>();
resultados.add(new int[] {2, 0, 3, 1});
resultados.add(new int[] {1, 3, 0, 2});
resultados.add(new int[] {1, 2, 0, 3});

Collections.sort(resultados, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    @OverrideC
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
      if(a[0] - b[0]==0)
      {
          return a[1]-b[1];
      }
      else
          return a[0]-b[0];
    }
});

//imprimir en consola
for (int[] r : resultados) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r));
}
```

Un snippet con tu ejemplo aqui: https://rextester.com/TNX33407

Comment: Es curioso, en mi programa no me realiza la ordenación, sin embargo si ejecuto este código en una clase aparte me lo realiza. Pero no entiendo por qué. He revisado todo, nombres de variables, etc. Y nada. En mi clase no se ordena, y en otra distinta sí funciona...